# javafx setDisable() not working when called from outside the class controller

Tags: java, javafx, controllers

i'm working on a school project rn, and facing a problem with enabling buttons after selecting a row from a table, the buttons and the tableView are in 2 different fxml files, so i use a getController() to call the methode that enables them, but it's not working, i tried a system.out and it worked fine, but not setDisable()
here's the code in the tableView controller:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    stock.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED , (e) -> {
        Produit p=null;
        p = stock.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if(p!=null){

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sideStock.fxml"));
            try {
                Parent root= (Parent)loader.load();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StockController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            SideStockController controller=loader.getController();
            controller.active();



        }    
     });
    //some other methods
    initCol();
    resize(stock);
    initDataInTable();

}
```

and here's the method i'm trying to call

```
public void active() {

    modifier.setDisable(false);
    supprimer.setDisable(false);
    entree.setDisable(false);
}
```

it worked fine when i called it from another method in the same class..

both fxml files are loaded in the same scene, in UImain.fxml/initialize()

Comment: You are creating a new controller, which is separate to the one controlling the view. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205187/fxmlloader-cannot-find-running-controller-instance-and-creates-new-one)

Comment: thanks, i understand now where's the problem, but that solution didn't work for me, i'm trying similar things rn